# How to get multiple matches as a single string with Regex

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string, winforms

I have a textbox on my form that takes in any string of text, say a user typed in `"Hello 184;%88 World"` .

I've got three textboxes, one to display only Numbers/Digits typed in, the next to display only Letters contained in the String and the last textbox to display   only symbols or special characters in the string.

So far I've tried looping through the string using a `For Each` statement but I wasn't comfortable with it so I decided to stick with VB.net's Regex Class.  And here's what I could come up with to display something in the textbox for numbers and digits in the string:

```
Private Sub ScanButton_Click(ByVal sender as System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ScanButton.Click

Dim TextEntry As String = StringBox.Text 

Dim IntResult As Match = Regex.Match(TextEntry, "\d+")

Numbox.Text = IntResult.Value

End Sub
```

I already imported `System.Text.RegularExpressions`

For example, after I type in:

" ashsjshsuie14568 hdidihgsib2822"

The textbox for the numbers in the string only shows `14568` omitting `2822` .

I have no idea how to make just letters and symbols from the string appear in their respective textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you can have multiple matches, so just getting the result of `Regex.Match` will return only the first match.  Instead if you wanted to use match, use `Regex.Matches` instead.

However a better idea, might be to replace the characters you don't want out of the string, instead of trying to find the ones you do:

```
Dim textEntry As String = StringBox.Text 
Dim intResult As String = Regex.Replace(textEntry, "\D", "")
Dim letterResult As String = Regex.Replace(textEntry, "[^a-zA-Z]", "")
Dim symbolResult As String = Regex.Replace(textEntry, "[0-9a-zA-Z]", "")
```

In the example above, `intResult` removes all non-digit characters (that's what `\D` class matches), `letterResult` removes everything except a-z, and `symbolResult` removes numbers and letters.  That should produce what you want.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, just one more thing out of curiousity, what do the empty `"" ` characters do?

Comment: The empty characters are what you replace the found characters with.